Jquery autoscroll wrong div
So i read 10+ Threads about this but still didnt find a solution.
I want to autoscroll to the bottom but always the main div is scrolled not the one i want.
The autoscroll must be in div2
My code:
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="div2">
<div id="autoscroll"></div>

</div>
</div>

My attempts(both autoscroll the wrong div)
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const d = document.querySelector('#autoscroll');
   d.scrollIntoView();
});
</script>

<script>
$("#autoscroll")[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "end" 
});
</script>

I was expecting to autoscroll the right div.

Dude, it works:


$("#autoscroll")[0].scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "end" 
});
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 200dvh 0;
}

#div2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div2">
  <div id="autoscroll"></div>
</div>



